# How to store DateTime with exact decimals in SQL Server using Java

Tags: java, sql-server, informix

I am trying to get Datetime from Informix and stored it in SQL Server through Java by using `java.util.Date` datatype in Java and `datetime2` datatype in SQL Server but I am getting decimals difference between SQL data and Informix data and this creates a comparison problem for me.

Can anyone suggest me to fix this decimal mismatch?

Comment: Don't use `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`, they are just causing trouble. Use the classes from `java.time`, you can properly define offsets and time zones. A good lecture might be one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766674/java-convert-java-time-instant-to-java-sql-timestamp-without-zone-offset) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58099500/issue-in-saving-current-date-with-utc-time-in-sql-server) given by @BasilBorque.